# Access javascript objects that are having same name

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a groups user control and javascript is defined inside the control. In a page, I have two such controls, which work independently. Rendered javascript is something similar to below:

```
//control 1
var Groups = (function () {
var obj = {};
obj.selectedid = 2;
return obj;
}());

//control 2
var Groups = (function () {
var obj = {};
obj.selectedid = 2; //it is different here, to keep it simple i just hardcoded as '2'
return obj;
}());
```

Could anyone please tell me how to access 1st Groups variable (control) on the Page. I thought something like Groups[0] would give me the result but it's not.

---

Thanks for your replies. Much Appreciated. I am adding more information to be clear. User control contains dual listbox, user can add/remove values from list1 to list2. So I had encapsulated all this logic as below.

```
    var Groups = (function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.selectedid = 2;

    //some local functions for internal operations such as
    function moveGroups(source, target){        
    }

     //there are public functions to initialize this control or to add groups as below 
    // Groups can be added from external page by calling  Groups.AddGroups(data);
    obj.AddGroups = function(data) {
           //refers to local variables and functions and adds data to listboxes
      };

    return obj;
    }());
```

Problem is I have two such Groups controls on the page. Group1 contains its own dual list and similarly Group2. Now, I would need to access AddGroups function of both objects work independently like Groups1.AddGroups(data) or Groups2.AddGroups(data) from the page.

---

I have worked out with below solution.

```
var Groups = Groups || []; //Check object already exists
Groups.push( 
//kept all the existing code here...
(function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.selectedid = 2;

    //some local functions for internal operations such as
    function moveGroups(source, target){        
    }

     //there are public functions to initialize this control or to add groups as below 
    // Groups can be added from external page by calling  Groups.AddGroups(data);
    obj.AddGroups = function(data) {
           //refers to local variables and functions and adds data to listboxes
      };

    return obj;
    }())

);
```

Now in my page, I refer using:

```
Groups[0].AddAvailGroups();
Groups[1].AddAvailGroups();
```

Comment: Your second `Groups` variable is overwriting your first `Groups` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two `var Groups` declarations define the same memory location.

So your second statement

```
//control 2
var Groups = (function () {
```

will overwrite value stored previously in Groups variable.

If you want to access Groups as a collection you should do this explicitly:

```
var Groups = []; // array/list;

Groups.push( ... ); // control 1
Groups.push( ... ); // control 2
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how to define the collection, since in the user control I don't know how many times it is placed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If both these snippets declare a global (*EVIL*) variable `Groups`, then the first object is lost forever once the second anonymous function is invoked. It's as simple as that, I'm afraid. If they're not globals, and part of different scopes, then it's a simple matter of accessing the property:

```
Groups.selectedid;//will be either 1 or 2 depending on the scope.
```

The value of groups is a reference to the `obj` object, the anonymous function is declared and invoked immediately (closure), and returns an object, with `selectedid` as a property. Therefore `Group` has that property. `Groups[0]` would work if your code were something along the lines of:

```
var Groups = (function()//assign return value
{
    return [2];//return this value
})();//call the function
```

Comment: I think I have same code as displayed and unable to access Groups[0].

Comment: Oh, I am missing return as array. But in my case, it's not just a array. It is a object which has public variables and functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give two different names :

```
var Groups1 = ...

var Groups2 = ...
```

After that you may access `Groups1.selectedid`

But it's unclear for me what's the purpose of those objects and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Through

```
Groups.selectedid
```

But if it's in the same code, won't work, because you assigned different values to the same variables. You need to separate:

```
var Groups1 = ...
var Groups2 = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should generate GUID(this can be id of control plus some prefix) inside your control for js variable that should be referred to group.
And create global array with them. In this case you will be able in any time to have access to  your groups